# Como executar o emulador a partir da linha de comandos do windows?

Tags: android, android-studio

Como posso executar o Emulador Android sem ter de abrir o Android Studio?
o comando:

> android avd

não funciona.

Quando uso o comando :

> emulator -avd nexus5

Recebo esse mensagem de erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para executar um emulador via linha de comandos use o seguinte comando:

```
emulator -avd avd_name [ {-option [value]} … ]
```

Por exemplo, se tiver um emulador com o nome *Nexus_5X_API_25_x86* o seguinte comando irá lançá-lo.

```
emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_25_x86
```

Para listar os nomes dos emuladores existentes use o comando

```
emulator -list-avds
```

Os comandos devem ser executados dentro da pasta onde se encontra o *emulator.exe*, por padrão em

```
C:\Users\NomeDoUtilizador\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools>
```

ou usar o caminho completo para o *emulator.exe*

```
C:\Users\NomeDoUtilizador\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_25_x86
C:\Users\NomeDoUtilizador\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator -list-avds
```

Comment: Recebo esse erro: [6892]:ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ..\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
Could not launch '..\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe': No such file or directory

Comment: Em que pasta está o *emulator.exe*?

Comment: Consegui executar, apenas inserir o caminho : path/to/Sdk/emulator -use-system-libs -avd [AVD-NAME]

Answer (score 2):

Tive problema no Linux:

> emulator: command not found (comando não encontrado)

como essa solução pode ajudar alguém estou colocando aqui.

entre no local da pasta do SDK do Android em sua Maquina  exemplo **/home/user/android/sdk/tool** execute o mesmo comando, só que iniciando com ***"./"*** ficando assim:

```
./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_25_x86
```

Answer (score -2):

Escreve um arquivo nomeado como Android.vbs com o conteúdo abaixo:
Write a file named as Android.vbs with this content:

```
Dim WShell
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WShell.Run "%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator\emulator.exe -avd androidtest -writable-system", 0
Set WShell = Nothing
```

Acima temos um script que irá iniciar o emulador do Android nomeado como androidtest, e é como se fosse uma VM, pois é usado qemu para carregar a máquina androidtest para a memória e rodar o Android referido. Este é um script que pode ser criado na área de trabalho do Windows, por meio do bloco de notas, por exemplo.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).