# Como criar um emulador sem utilizar a ide?

Tags: android, emulador, android-sdk

Eu preciso emular o android na minha máquina, mas não queria utilizar uma máquina virtual porque utilizaria muitos recursos, queria usar o sdk tools do android studio, mas também não queria instalar o android studio para isso.

Então eu baixei o sdk tools no site do android studio e tentei rodar, nas versões antigas tinha uma gui e era bem simples para criar e rodar, mas na versão atual não tem, é tudo via comando, tentei ate executar alguns mas nenhum foi bem sucedido.

Executei isso:

```
C:\Users\Futurotec\Downloads\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\tools>android
**************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************

Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

Então tentei rodar o comando android create avd:

```
C:\Users\Futurotec\Downloads\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\tools>android create avd
**************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************

Invoking "C:\Users\Futurotec\Downloads\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\tools\bin\avdmanager" create avd

Error: The parameters --package, --name must be defined for action 'create avd'

Usage:
      avdmanager [global options] create avd [action options]
      Global options:
  -s --silent     : Silent mode, shows errors only.
  -v --verbose    : Verbose mode, shows errors, warnings and all messages.
     --clear-cache: Clear the SDK Manager repository manifest cache.
  -h --help       : Help on a specific command.

Action "create avd":
  Creates a new Android Virtual Device.
Options:
  -a --snapshot: Place a snapshots file in the AVD, to enable persistence.
  -c --sdcard  : Path to a shared SD card image, or size of a new sdcard for
                 the new AVD.
  -g --tag     : The sys-img tag to use for the AVD. The default is to
                 auto-select if the platform has only one tag for its system
                 images.
  -p --path    : Directory where the new AVD will be created.
  -k --package : Package path of the system image for this AVD (e.g.
                 'system-images;android-19;google_apis;x86'). [required]
  -n --name    : Name of the new AVD. [required]
  -f --force   : Forces creation (overwrites an existing AVD)
  -b --abi     : The ABI to use for the AVD. The default is to auto-select the
                 ABI if the platform has only one ABI for its system images.
  -d --device  : The optional device definition to use. Can be a device index
                 or id.
```

Tentei varias parâmetros, mas nenhum criava o emulador.

Tentei utilizar também o comando avdmanager direto, mas apresentou as mesmas mensagens.

Em todas as minhas pesquisas só encontrava soluções que era necessário abrir o android studio ou que os comandos eram das versões antiga.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como executar o emulador a partir da linha de comandos do windows?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203299/2541)

Comment: @ramaral executar eu já consigo, mas criar não.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Um exemplo de comando válido para criar um avd:

`avdmanager create avd -n "Meu-Emulador" -k "system-images;android-26;google_apis_playstore;x86"`

---

### avdmanager

O programa utilizado para criar AVDs é o `avdmanager`. Ele está localizado em `sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager`. O `android` também funcionaria, mas ele acaba utilizando o `avdmanager` por baixo.

Para a criação de um AVD dois parâmetros são obrigatórios:

- `-n` ou `--name` para nomear o AVD
- `-k` ou `--package` para indicar qual imagem de sistema será utilizada

---

### Imagens de sistema

Para a criação de AVDs é **obrigatório** indicar uma imagem de sistema. Para listar as imagens instaladas, utilize o mesmo comando **sem** o parâmetro `-k`:

`avdmanager create avd -n "Meu-Emulador"`

Se nenhuma imagem for listada, significa que nenhuma foi instalada. A instalação de novas imagens pode ser feita através da utilização do `sdkmanager`.

**Para listar os pacotes disponíveis:**

```
sdkmanager --list --verbose
```

Nota: o `--verbose` foi utilizado para [não truncar os nomes dos pacotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521077).

**Para instalar uma imagem:**

```
sdkmanager "system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86"
```

---

### Executando o avd no emulador

Para iniciar o emulador, utilize o programa `emulator`, localizado em `sdk/tools/emulator`, informando o nome do AVD a ser executado:

```
emulator -avd "Meu-Emulador"
```

Comment: Eu consigo listar o que eu posso adicionar no parâmetro "-k"? Copiei exatamente o seu comando e apresentou a seguinte mensagem "Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:", e como faço para baixar as plataformas?

Comment: Se rodar o comando sem o parâmetro `-k`, ele vai listar todos os packages disponíveis. Os packages são basicamente as imagens de sistema que estão na pasta `sdk\system-images`. No meu caso eu tenho a pasta `sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis_playstore/x86` com uma imagem, que acaba "virando" o package `system-images;android-26;google_apis_playstore;x86`

Comment: Executei "avdmanager -k", e apresentou a seguinte mensagem: Error: Flag '-k' is not a valid global flag. Did you mean to specify it after the verb/object name?

Comment: É o contrário: rodar **sem** o `-k`. Ex.: `avdmanager create avd -n "Meu-Emulador"`. Assim ele vai listar os packages (caso existam).

Comment: não apareceu, será que é porque eu não tenho nenhum, e tem como baixar utilizando os comandos também?

Comment: Eu tenho duas pastas aqui com o sdk, uma "virgem" e outra que utilizo no android studio, a que utilizo no android studio aparece os packages quando executo o comando, mas na "virgem" não, tem como eu baixar os packages na virgem? Estou precisando disso, de colocar o sdk sem o android studio em outra maquina, ai preciso fazer este processo do zero.

Comment: `sdkmanager --list --verbose` lista todos pacotes do SDK disponíveis para instalação. Imagens de sistema tem o nome começando com `system-images;`. Pra instalar alguma, só chamar o `sdkmanager` de novo passando o nome do pacote: `sdkmanager "system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86"`

Comment: Criei, mas na hora de executar apresenta a seguinte mensagem: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Comment: Seu erro já foge do escopo da pergunta. Essa mensagem indica que há um erro na configuração do sdk ou algo semelhante. [Link relevante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44386974)

Comment: Esta certo, só uma ultima pergunta antes de marcar sua pergunta como a certa, porque você colocou "TL;DR" no titulo?

Comment: A maquina que eu criei no android studio rodou normalmente, mas a maquina criada com este comando, apresenta este erro: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Comment: `tl;dr` significa `too long; didn`t read`. Normalmente é utilizado para destacar um resumo geral ou o ponto mais importante de toda a reposta.

Comment: Referente ao erro: de uma olhada no link, tem várias causas prováveis e soluções. O fato de vc estar usando dois sdks diferentes com pacotes diferentes instalados pode estar influenciando.